# Error within login functionality in node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm new to node.js and I'm trying to sign in users using an API that I've created. The login API should return the token corresponding to the logged-in user alongside his role. I'm getting a token object as a map of the token itself alongside the role. The following screenshot shows the response:

[image]

But it should return:

```
{
"token": {
        "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6NCwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJiYmIiLCJyb2xlIjoibWVkZWNpbiIsImlhdCI6MTY0OTg0NDY0NiwiZXhwIjoxNjQ5OTMxMDQ2fQ.nSwawXpig72t0ySxQNUUFdXT03eC6jmtgQs9jtsbFbk",
    },
"user": {
            "id": 4,
            "role": "medecin"
        }
}
```

Here is my code in which the resolve methods returns both token obj and user obj separately:

```
const privateKey = "this is a private key dsfdsgfqdsmlkfsdmqlf,kqdmsjdsmjfm"

exports.login=(email, password)=>{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        db.User.findOne({where: {email:email}}).then(user=>{
            if (!user){
                reject('Invalid email and password')
            }
            {
                bcrypt.compare(password, user.password).then(same=>{
                    if(same){
                        let token = jwt.sign({id: user.id, username: user.username, role:user.role}, privateKey,
                        {expiresIn:"24h"})
                        resolve({ token, user: { id: user.id, role: user.role } })
                    }
                    else{
                        reject('Invalid email and password')
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Can anyone help me out with this? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to return

```
{ token: { token }, user: { id: user.id, role: user.role } }
```

EDIT:
From the comments, it seems that the object which is resolved from this function is assigned to the "token" property of some other object where the login function is used. You can verify the code from where you're calling the login function.

Comment: It's now returning a token object that holds both the token and the user objects inside:

{
    "token": {
        "token": {
            "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZ...."
        },
        "user": {
            "id": 4,
            "role": "medecin"
        }
    }
}

Comment: Can you test it by returning an empty object? @Kaisama

Comment: It indeed returns an empty object: "token": {}

Comment: It means there's a problem outside this function. The object which is resolved from here is assigned to the  "token" property of the outer object

Comment: I'll try to find the issue, thanks man!